# xVal and Regular Expression Match

Tags: asp.net, regex, xval

I am using xVal to validate my forms in asp.net MVC 1.0

Not sure why my regular expression isn't validating correctly.

- It does **NOT** validate with an empty value
- It does **NOT** validate with the value of "1", "12", "123", or "1234"
- It validates with the value of
  "12345"
- It validates with the value of "12345 "
- It validates with the value of "12345 -"
- It validates with the value of "12345 -1"
- It validates with the value of "12345 -12" ... etc

For a zip code I expect one of the two patterns:

`12345` or `12345 -1234`

Here are the two regex I tried:

```
(\d{5})((( -)(\d{4}))?)

(\d{5})|(\d{5} -\d{4})
```

Here is my MetaData class for xVal

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TIDProfileMetadata))]
public class TIDProfileStep
{
   public class TIDProfileMetadata
   {
       [Required(ErrorMessage = " [Required] ")]
       [RegularExpression(@"(\d{5})|(\d{5} -\d{4})", ErrorMessage = " Invalid Zip ")]
       public string Zip { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Here is my aspx page:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Profile", FormMethod.Post); %>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <td>
      <h6>Zip:</h6>
   </td>
   <td>
      <%= Html.TextBox("Profile.Zip")%>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="submit"/>
   </td> 
</tr>
</table>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>

<% Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
        .OnDocumentReady(() =>
   { %>
   <%= Html.ClientSideValidation<TIDProfileStep>("Profile").SuppressScriptTags() %>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed to mention that I was using a mask plugin for my input field.
The mask plugin can be found [here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

So on the text box if I were to fill in only the first 5 digits and then tab to the next field is would validate as false due to the mask plugin I have used. The mask plugin, puts in an underscore character for empty possiblities.... So for example:

`_____ -____` would be the mask that it would put in the empty field on focus. If I fill in the first 5 digits I would have:

`12345 -____`

Then if I tab to the next field, the `-____` is removed, but the input field needs to be re-validated onblur.

So what I did was re-validate the input field on blur and now it works.

```
$('#Zip').blur(function() {
        $(this).validate();
});
```

I use this regex `^\d{5}( -\d{4})?$`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the start and end anchors:

```
^\d{5}( -\d{4})?$
```

Without these you allow partial matching. The regex matches the string `12345 -1` by `\d{5}`: **`12345`**`-1`, and validates it.

Comment: I did have the start and end anchors before, took them out and forgot to say I tried them. I have found that it was fighting with my mask plugin. +1 for pointing out the anchors tho, I should have mentioned I used them.